Jetpack Compose: Drawing outside of Composable bounds While using Transparent Colors
I'm creating a custom component in Jetpack Compose that needs to be drawn beyond the component's bounds, Which might use transparent color in BlendMode. I'm using CompositingStrategy for handling this but facing some issues.
Below is the example recreation of the issue.
@Composable
@Preview(widthDp = 600, heightDp = 600)
private fun Preview() {
    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Blue),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier.size(250.dp).graphicsLayer(
                compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen,
//                compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.ModulateAlpha
            ).border(1.dp, color = Color.Black)
        ) {
            drawCircle(
                Color.Red,
                (size.minDimension/2f)*1.5f
            )
            drawCircle(
                Color.Transparent,
                (size.minDimension/2f)*1f,
                blendMode = BlendMode.Src
            )
        }
    }
}


On using CompositingStrategy.Offscreen: Handles alpha correctly but clips the drawing to the component's size.



On using CompositingStrategy.ModulateAlpha: Solves the clipping issue, but transparent colors Inner Circle are not working.


So is there any way of achieving both of these at the same time?
Below is the Result i am expecting, where the inner circle is transparent, So the blue background is visible:


compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen

clips content in Composable and Modifiers after it.
By default even if you can draw anything to any Composable even if their size is zero.
To apply Porter-Duff or blend modes correctly you can create a layer with
private fun DrawScope.drawWithLayer(block: DrawScope.() -> Unit) {
    with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
        val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)
        block()
        restoreToCount(checkPoint)
    }
}

And draw inside it with
@Composable
@Preview(widthDp = 600, heightDp = 600)
private fun Preview() {
    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Blue),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier.size(250.dp)
                .border(1.dp, color = Color.Black)
        ) {

            drawWithLayer {
                drawCircle(
                    Color.Red,
                    (size.minDimension/2f)*1.5f
                )
                drawCircle(
                    Color.Transparent,
                    (size.minDimension/2f)*1f,
                    blendMode = BlendMode.Src
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


Jetpack Compose Applying PorterDuffMode to Image
How to clip or cut a Composable?

It works, but on docs i found, it has a significant performance overhead. So is there any other efficient way to achieve this Or to reduce this overhead?

There is no significant performance overhead with this. I have been using this almost 4 years and in about 5 libraries including image cropper with 4k images and had no issues. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Cropper

And initially before coming up with graphicsLayer CompositingStrategy.Offscreen, jetpack compose was using this under the hood by when you set alpha less than 1f if you check first link. And i have never heard anyone complaining or creating an issue for setting alpha creating any performance issues.

I found the line they use it in source code as well. If you set alpha less than 1f or inside graphicsLayer they also save layer as i posted in answer above. https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/ui/ui/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/GraphicsLayerOwnerLayer.android.kt;drc=655aebc272ea0b0371b065af7d87a87bd4250928;l=267. And it's very likely CompositingStrategy.Offscreen does the same thing for blend modes to work. If there is a performance overhead, it should be with every solution possible because both are offscreen buffer

You can create the shape you mention using "difference" path operation:
create a path for the outer circle and a path for the inner circle, then take the difference between the two paths, which gives the shape you mention.
Code:
@Composable
@Preview(widthDp = 600, heightDp = 600)
fun App() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Blue),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(250.dp)
                .border(1.dp, color = Color.Black)
        ) {

            val cx = size.width/2f
            val cy = size.height/2f

            val c = Offset(cx, cy)

            val r = (size.minDimension/2f)

            val outerPath = Path().apply {
                addOval(
                    oval = Rect(
                        center = c,
                        radius = r*1.5f
                    )
                )
            }

            val innerPath = Path().apply {
                addOval(
                    oval = Rect(
                        center = c,
                        radius = r
                    )
                )
            }

            val path = Path().apply {
                op(outerPath, innerPath, PathOperation.Difference)
            }

            drawPath(
                path = path,
                color = Color.Red
            )
        }
    }
}

Result:


Thanks, but your code is to clip with inner circle. But what i want is to draw inner circle with a specific color which might have a alpha value to specify transparency through the component.
